Server 500 error when Dto class name exists in two separate DtoModels folders
I have an odd error. I'm testing a C# Web API application. The structure for the controllers is the following:
-US (FOLDER) -> UsersController.cs
-EU (FOLDER) -> UsersController.cs

Then I have a DtoModels folder for both separate regions. Like this - DtoModels:
   -US (FOLDER) -> Users (FOLDER) -> UserDto.cs
   -EU (FOLDER) -> Users (FOLDER) -> UserDto.cs

Then I have simple endpoint in both controllers like this:
[HttpPost("AddUser")]
public async Task<IActionResult> AddUser(UserDto data)
{
        try
        {
            if (data is not null)
            {
                await _usersService.CreateUser(new Models.EU.User() { Name = data.Name, Email = data.Email });

                return Ok();
            }
            else
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

            return BadRequest();
        }
}

I include the namespace to each controller.
Controllers -> US -> UsersController.cs

using WebApplication1.DtoModels.US.Users;


Controllers -> EU -> UsersController.cs

using WebApplication1.DtoModels.EU.Users;

Even the namespace is clearly set, my application is crashing, to be specific is throwing error 500.
However, if I use the namespace of US to EU controller like:
using WebApplication1.DtoModels.US.Users;

Then the application is working, which is kind of odd. I tried directly to include the namespace as:
  public async Task<IActionResult> AddUser(DtoModels.EU.Users.UserDto data)

but it didn't help.
Note: I would like to keep those dto's separate.
Any hint how can I solve this?


What kind of exception is thrown? 2. I suspect this might be wrong new Models.EU.User()


Swagger-> Failed to load API definition. Errors:  Fetch error response status is 500

It is because Swagger registers models with SchemaId set to class name by default.
To work around that, you need to specify custom generation of SchemaIds.
In your case the simpliest solution would be to call:
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => 
    options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName));

This would remove ambiguity by using fullname of a type (so namespace included).
UPDATE
Minimal example using minimal APIs:
var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();
builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options => options.CustomSchemaIds(type => type.FullName));

var app = builder.Build();

if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();

// Note different namespaces of the User type.
app.MapGet("/get-us-user", () => new testprojects.US.User()).WithOpenApi();
app.MapGet("/get-eu-user", () => new testprojects.EU.User()).WithOpenApi();

app.Run();

UPDATE
Removing Swagger altogether is also an option. The error will go away together with it.

This will not work with me, I might have around 50 dto models to each region. if I remove swagger does this error will disappear?

@OdwMai Yes, error is caused by swagger and removing it altogether will remove the error as well!

it works, I guess I would need to look for swagger alternative. thank you :)

@OdwMai  If my answer was helpful, you should accept/upvote it
